# Change Tab Bar When Notification is Clicked

Tags: swift, push-notification, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate, onesignal

Whenever the user gets a notification and they click it, they should be taken to that specific tab. For instance, when a user gets a message and they open the notification, the app should open up but to the messages tab. Think of twitter & dm's.
With my project, Im trying to implement something very similar. In the appdelegate and notificationReceived (OneSignal for Push notifications), I've attempted to do so by this:

```
 let sb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let messageNavigationController: UINavigationController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesNav") as! UINavigationController
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = messageNavigationController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But nothing happens. Whenever a user receives a notification, the app just opens up one the main tab (tab 0). What am i doing incorrectly?

Comment: BTW, if you're using a smartphone, what are you clicking, or clicking with? Do you have a mouse connected to your device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by notificationReceived, that's not a predefined function of `UIApplicationDelegate`. If you want to open different pages when a push notification happens with OneSignal you should probably pass your handling function to the `handleNotificationAction` of `OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions`.

Also you mention changing tabs in your tab controller but the code you pasted is setting your root view to a `UINavigationController`. If you actually want to change tabs you need to get a reference to the tab controller and set the correct `selectedIndex` on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it out by moving that over to the handle notification action & the custom tab bar controller class.